# Dit-on « sur l’application mobile ou dans l’application mobile »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions

Exemple:

Cette offre est disponible seulement sur/dans l’application mobile de McDonald’s.

Quelle règle commande l’une ou l’autre de ces prépositions?

Merci!

Comment: *Avec l'application*, même si elle est incluse dans cette dernière, on ne peut avoir l'une sans l'autre.

Comment: Vous les trouverez ici sur notre site et sur l’appli McDonald’s† au moment de passer une commande mobile. De plus, si vous commandez avec l’appli, vous pourrez récupérer votre repas au service-au-volant, au service au stationnement* ou au comptoir. –

Comment: Source: www4.mcdonalds.ca/bons-rabais

Comment: Est-ce à dire que les personnes chargées des publicités pour le compte de McDonald’s ne maîtrisent pas leur français?

Comment: Avec *sur le site*, l'application étant incluse dans le site, *sur l'application* est cohérent, on pourrait remplacer les *sur* par *dans* en gardant cette cohérence ; *sur* les IHM (à la surface) du site, *dans* les données/outils du site sans commettre de faute de français. *Avec l'application* convient aussi dans ces deux cas.

Comment: Le marketing utilise le langage du public ciblé, il reste ici dans l'usage courant, il doit être cohérent sur l'ensemble du site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il y a beaucoup de prépositions possibles. L'usage ne s'est pas encore fixé.

> [Accédez à nos services en ligne sur l’Espace Client Internet et **sur** l’application mobile](https://www.labanquepostale.fr/particulier/mbp/ma_banque_digitale.html)

> [Les fonctionnalités disponibles depuis votre Espace Client Internet et **depuis** l’application mobile)(https://www.labanquepostale.fr/particulier/mbp/ma_banque_digitale.html)   *(même page que **sur** !)*

> [Les services disponibles **dans** l’application mobile](https://www.savoirsnumeriques62.fr/bienvenue-/l-application-mobile/)

> [Participer à une réunion à partir de l’application mobile](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/participer-%C3%A0-une-r%C3%A9union-%C3%A0-partir-de-l-application-mobile-teams-d275c769-7dd6-470d-bb97-44a26b82aa07)

> [Avec l’application mobile […], tous vos services en ligne sont sur votre smartphone !](https://www.mutuellemgc.fr/actualite/lancement-application-mobile-MGC/)

Et aussi, nettement moins courants :

> [Comment commander par l'application mobile](https://inone.zendesk.com/hc/fr/sections/200135756-Comment-commander-par-l-application-mobile)

> [Est-il possible d'installer Mathjax sous l'application Mobile](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=411136)

La préposition ***sur*** est utilisée pour les applications mobiles, parce qu'elles sont perçues comme équivalentes à des sites webs. Elles est beaucoup plus rare pour les applications sur un ordinateur de bureau.

La préposition ***dans*** est la plus courante pour les applications sur un ordinateur de bureau (mais on trouve aussi ***sur*** et ***sous***). Elle convient aussi aux applications mobiles, mais là ***sur*** lui fait beaucoup de concurrence.

On peut aussi utiliser *depuis*, *à partir de* ou *avec* lorsque la phrase n'est pas trop éloignée du sens naturel de ces prépositions, ce qui est en général le cas. Si l'on peut accomplir une tâche en commençant par lancer l'application, *depuis* et *à partir de* conviennent. Si l'on peut accomplir une tâche en utilisant l'application, *avec* convient.

Ma réponse concerne la France. Je ne sais pas si l'usage est différent ailleurs.

Answer (score -1):

Ni l'une ni l'autre des prépositions ne semble vraiment convenir: l'application est un ensemble de concepts qui servent à produire des résultats ;  l'offre n'est qu'un résultat, tout comme le nom de l'application, que l'on pourra lire sur un écran qu'elle contrôle; elle ne se trouve pas *dans* les concepts ni *dessus*.

On peut peut-être trouver acceptable de parler d'une façon  transcendante, et alors il faudrait trouver un biais qui donne soit à « dans » soit à  « sur » un minimum de logique (ou tout au moins le plus de logique possible).  On dit par exemple, « écouter ceci *sur* France inter »: on transcende  « émission » en un point physique qui est le réglage de la station sur un cadran radio. Cependant je ne vois pas de possibilité similaire dans le domaine des  applications.

Pout ma part, je m'en tiendrais à une préposition comme « **à partir de** » par souci d'associer aux  relations qu'expriment les mots une réalité fidèle à leur sens.

- Cette offre est disponible seulement **à partir de** l’application mobile de McDonald’s.

Comment: Vous les trouverez ici sur notre site et sur l’appli McDonald’s† au moment de passer une commande mobile. De plus, si vous commandez avec l’appli, vous pourrez récupérer votre repas au service-au-volant, au service au stationnement* ou au comptoir.

Comment: Source: https://www4.mcdonalds.ca/bons-rabais/

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Alors il doit y en avoir d'autres ; « sur » me semble meilleur que « dans », de toute façon.